# storage classes in C language

Tags: c

In this program i am not declaring any variable still is showing data segment (BSS) size as 8 bytes.why ?

```
achul@achul:~/chennai/misclaneous$ vi memory.c
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
}
achul@achul:~/chennai/misclaneous$ cc memory.c -o mem
achul@achul:~/chennai/misclaneous$ size mem
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1056     252       8    1316     524 mem
```

here i am not using any global variable as BSS is reserved for global variable only anyone plz ?

Comment: The posted code isn't the only you compile. Startup code is linked too.

Comment: Yes, compile with a `-c` option to obtain just the object `.o` that corresponds  to your code.

Comment: I do not see how this is related to storage class specifiers. This is a normal executable/object issue.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
int i;
main()
{
}
/*
cc -c memory.c
achul@achul:~/chennai/misclaneous$ size memory.o
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
     61       0       0      61      3d memory.o
why uninitialized var not going into BSS ?
*/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a normal (*hosted*) environment, the .c files and compiled to object files, and this object files are linked with the standard clib. And the library contains a module (generally called crt0.o) that is natively loaded by the system, optionnaly decodes the command line and calls the function  `main` passing `argc`, `argv` and `environment`, and also generally sets some global variables.

This crt0 module does contain global variables.

Answer (score 1):

Here are couple of outputs

Below is a compiled object and not at all linked, purely the simple program above with no global content as indicated.

> ```
> size   t1.o 
>    text      data     bss     dec     hex filename
>      62         0       0      62      3e t1.o
>
> size --format=SysV t1.o 
> t1.o  :
> section           size   addr
> .text                6      0
> .data                0      0
> .bss                 0      0
> .comment            42      0
> .note.GNU-stack      0      0
> .eh_frame           56      0
> Total              104
> ```

And this Below is a complete executable likned with startup code and other supported stuff.

> ```
> size a.out 
>    text      data     bss     dec     hex filename
>    1115       552       8    1675     68b a.out
>
>  size --format=SysV a.out 
> a.out  :
> section              size      addr
> .interp                28   4194872
> .note.ABI-tag          32   4194900
> .note.gnu.build-id     36   4194932
> .gnu.hash              28   4194968
> .dynsym                72   4195000
> .dynstr                56   4195072
> .gnu.version            6   4195128
> .gnu.version_r         32   4195136
> .rela.dyn              24   4195168
> .rela.plt              48   4195192
> .init                  26   4195240
> .plt                   48   4195280
> .text                 370   4195328
> .fini                   9   4195700
> .rodata                 4   4195712
> .eh_frame_hdr          52   4195716
> .eh_frame             244   4195768
> .init_array             8   6295056
> .fini_array             8   6295064
> .jcr                    8   6295072
> .dynamic              464   6295080
> .got                    8   6295544
> .got.plt               40   6295552
> .data                  16   6295592
> .bss                    8   6295608
> .comment               77         0
> Total                1752
> ```